# How to add images in front of treelist control of devexpress?

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have treelist that have four level child nodes.

> rootNode->1ChildNode.
>
> 1ChildNode->2ChildNode.
>
> 2ChildNode->3ChildNode.

[image: Screenshot of treelist]
I would like to provide image to each node of treelist. I set `rootNode.ImageIndex = 0` and `clientNode1.ImageIndex = 1` but it didn't work. Also, How can I bold or assign large font to 1ChildNode?
Can someone please let me know what I am missing?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation of [TreeListNode.ImageIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListNodesTreeListNode_SelectImageIndextopic) and [TreeListNode.StateImageIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListNodesTreeListNode_StateImageIndextopic) Property

**Select Image source:**

> The source of [select images](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument1073.aspx) is specified by the
>   [TreeList.SelectImageList](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_SelectImageListtopic.aspx) property. Certain select images are assigned
>   to nodes by indexes (zero-based integer values referring to images in
>   the **SelectImageList**).

**State Image source:**

> The source of [state images](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument1073.aspx) is specified by the [TreeList.StateImageList](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_StateImageListtopic.aspx)
>   property. Use the **StateImageIndex** property to associate certain state
>   images from this list with nodes.

You just need to set Selected or State image list property. after that these properties work property. Or you can set image at [TreeList.GetSelectImage](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_GetSelectImagetopic.aspx) and [TreeList.GetStateImage](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_GetStateImagetopic.aspx) event.